# NSLog (or other monitoring event) within UIWebView operations

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, nslog

I'm moderately experienced with iOS, but I'm using `UIWebView` for the first time on this project.

I'm wondering, is there a way to monitor the line-by-line, internal operations of a `UIWebView` in Xcode?  Maybe drop some NSLogs in there, or some breakpoints?  The delegate methods cover the pre- and post-load stuff, but there doesn't seem to be any interface to actually track what the WebView itself does when it loads a page.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to track the app's behavior as each image from a webpage is downloaded and stored.  I'm getting some weird errors around an image being unusable on iOS 7, but my PHP/JavaScript swears that everything is fine on its end, and the image seems fine on desktops and on iOS 6.  I'm increasingly certain that the problem has to do with the WebView itself, (an answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574193/has-ios-7-changed-png-compatibility-handling) seems to suggest it could be about WebKit calls on different threads), and I'd love to breakpoint my way through, or NSLog some key points or something, just to rule some stuff out.

Is anything like this possible?  Or is `UIWebView` a private party that you can only hear about once it's over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it break in Mobile Safari or only in your app?

You can point Safari's web inspector on OS X at Mobile Safari running in the iOS simulator or even on an iOS device (it has to be enabled in settings).

This will allow you to view all the HTTP headers and so on.

Another option is to use something like [wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to monitor TCP traffic, but that's a lot more complicated.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

[image]

Comment: I've played around with the Safari web inspector a bit, but my question is this: is that a representation of what is actually being stored on the iPhone, or is it just a glimpse of the same page?  The error I'm chasing has to do with how the iPhone handles files, so if the web inspector is just going to the same page (which it seems to be), it wouldn't really help...