# [WebCoreSharedBufferData getBytes:range:]: range {0, 8} exceeds data length 0'

Tags: cordova, ios7, cordova-3

I'm updating my application for iOs 7.I'd developed this application for cordova(phone gap). while i run this app, i got error:

```
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file
FirstDemo[175] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG Not a PNG file

FirstDemo[175:500b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[WebCoreSharedBufferData getBytes:range:]: range {0, 8} exceeds data length 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30875f4b 0x3af476af 0x30875e8d 0x311b0a91 0x307ce9a5 0x315afe47 0x315afd21 0x316f49ab 0x315afc75 0x315af8f9 0x315b80f5 0x315b771f 0x308fd45d 0x32c976b5 0x32c96b5f 0x32c82a91 0x32c825d5 0x32c7f371 0x32c7da71 0x3b431273 0x3b43106b 0x3b431ce1 0x3b431f59 0x3b56cdbf 0x3b56cc84)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm not able to find any soluation from any where.
can anyone help me?

Comment: We see this error as well, would you mind uploading you PNG files for analysis? Perhaps it is a certain type of PNG palette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, just updating this after realizing kcbanner's comment.

Have you seen/tried: [Has iOS 7 changed PNG compatibility/handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574193/has-ios-7-changed-png-compatibility-handling)

Comment: The errors occur from within a UIWebView, the programmer has no access to the data.

Comment: I have seen that actually, but we've tried many different kinds of PNGs and can't find a common factor that is causing this error.